# Mako Sytanx-Highlighting for Geany

Tags: syntax-highlighting, mako, geany

Is there a Mako-template syntax-highlighting for Geany? 
or would I need to make a customized one?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no Mako template build in available. As it looks very similar to plain HTML you might want to use that as basis.